# Prometheus targets based on ip address ranges?

Tags: monitoring, configuration-managment

Prometheus scrape targets based on ip address ranges?

I'm wondering if there is any way to configure Prometheus (great tool! thanks Brian B!) to scrape targets based only on range of ip address.

Like below:

12.34.56.0:9100 - 12.34.56.255:9100

What you think about it? Is it possible?

Yep, I checked docs and found only service discovery feature based on files. But it would be great just scrape everything from my vlan by only adding proper ip range.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If the method isn't documented, then I'm not sure it's possible.